# Java Guessing Game(Specifically JOptionPane)

Tags: java

So I recently taught myself a little bit of JOptionPane. I am trying to make a Guessing Game which utilizes the JOptionPane. Currently this is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessingGameJOptionPane {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int guess, numberToGuess, numberOfTries = 0;
    String input;
    boolean win;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    Random rand = new Random();

    numberToGuess = rand.nextInt(100);

    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, null,"Please enter your name.", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

    win = false;



    int guess1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,null,"Guess a number between 1 and 1000", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));

    while(win == false){


        numberOfTries++;

       if(numberToGuess < guess1)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The number you guessed was to low. Please try again" ,null , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        }
        else if(numberToGuess > guess1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The number you guessed was to high. Please try again" ,null , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations you won. The number was " + numberToGuess + ". It took you " + numberOfTries, null, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            win = true;
        }


    }//Win == False






}//Main Method
```

}//Class

After I enter the number it continuously says your number is to low or high and keeps creating a new Pane. Any help will be appreciated Thanks.

Comment: `while(win == false)` never exits if you enter in the wrong number. You may want to move the `int guess1 = ...` inside of the `while` loop, this way, it may display the question, then display the information message, and repeat until you get it correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem specifically lives here:

```
int guess1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,null,"Guess a number between 1 and 1000", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
while(win == false){ //Potential infinite loop begins here...
    numberOfTries++;
   if(numberToGuess < guess1)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The number you guessed was to low. Please try again" ,null , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if(numberToGuess > guess1){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The number you guessed was to high. Please try again" ,null , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations you won. The number was " + numberToGuess + ". It took you " + numberOfTries, null, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        win = true;
    }


}//Win == False
```

This loop will only ever exit if win = true.  However, this can only happen if a correct number is guessed.  An incorrect number entry will cause the loop to continue infinitely, as the only time the user can actually enter the number is *prior* to loop entry.  You can prove this by having your message dialog display the number of tries: you'll see each subsequent dialog will increase the tries by one.

Fortunately, the fix is easy:

```
while(win == false){ 
    int guess1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,null,"Guess a number between 1 and 1000", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)); //Moved this inside the loop
// ...rest is unchanged
```